# Update main class in pom when creating a project from an archetype

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, spring-boot-maven-plugin, archetypes

I'm working on an application leveraging Maven Archetypes. I've created an archetype and a project from it, but the main class reference in the pom file isn't getting updating, resulting in the generated project (which has different package names) referencing the main class of the original project. How can I update it during the generation of the derrivative project?

For example:
If parent project has Application.class in package `com.my_company.artifact_a`, then in pom we have a ref for `com.my_company.artifact_a.Application`; when we generate the derivative with different group and artifact ids, meaning now the app is in let's say, `com.your_company.artifact_b.Application`, the reference in the pom file will still be for `com.my_company.artifact_a.Application` when I'd like it to be updated to the new info when we run `maven archetype:create-from-project`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the archetype variables in the source files of your archetype. The values of those variables will be interpolated in your generated source files.

File src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/Application.java:

```
package ${package};

public class Application {
...
}
```

The package name will be set and the Application.java file will be put in the right folder for the specified package name.

Comment: I updated my question with an example, as the package references in the classes are updated fine during generation. Also, it's my understanding that using placeholders in classes makes the parent app un-runnable, no?

Comment: You can add those placeholder variables in the generated pom.xml too